# How to copy text from specific table <td> tag to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given this HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Copy This Text</td>
    <td><button type="button">Copy</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks on that button, how can I copy the the text from first `TD` tag to clipboard?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

The first way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
      $("td").append($("td").html());
   });
});
```

and you should remove the second `<td>` and put `button` outside

```
<button type="button">Copy</button>
```

Comment: How does this copy the text to the clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for jQuery:

```js
function copyText(obj) 
{
    var tmpInput = $("<input>");
    $("body").append(tmpInput);
    var tdVal = $(obj).parent().prev().text();
    tmpInput.val(tdVal).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    tmpInput.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Copy This Text</td>
    <td><button onclick="copyText(this)">Copy</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful for inexperienced coders if explained what your code does. Some comments in the code would be useful as would a brief summary of what you are doing. I know why you add an input, but it may not be obvious to others.